# Large text Python 3

Tags: fonts, size, extension-methods

Trying to get Python 3 to print large numerals, this is only recognize as text not as a digit.

```
A = input('?')

from guizero import App, Text
app = App()

writing = Text(app, text="A", color="red")

# Call the font_size() method
writing.font_size(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put "A" in quotes, this will print the letter A to the screen. If you want to reference the variable, you want to get rid of the quotes.

```
writing = Text(app, text=A, color="red")
```